# How to run data-flow job with google organization information?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

When I am executing dataflow template job using dataflow client api,It fails giving error which says precondition failure.

I have tried giving 'Project viewer/Owner' permissions and some of the permission from ResourceManager api to the service account I have created.
I would like to know if I am missing any required permission here or dataflow job can be run in organization scope as same code is working for google cloud project.

```
        .projects().templates()
        .launch(gcpCloudProject.getProjectId(), parameters) // here the project id is organization id in our case
        .setGcsPath("pathoftheGoogleBucketContainingTemplateCode");

    return launch.execute().getJob().getId();
```

Actual error message is `""errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"(8e77a6a351fca5e): Cannot get project information for project 546064730288.","reason":"failedPrecondition"}]"`

Comment: Hi there, can you confirm that you are inputting the correct project id? Unfortunately, it is easily confused with the project number.

Comment: @Cubez, I checked the project number which is right. My exact question was it is possible to launch dataflow, if I have a service account with right permission by providing the organisation id?

Comment: No, you can only use the project id. You cannot use the project number or the organization id.